# double and int in Eclipse

Tags: android, double, int

I am very new person to study in Android and I forget many Java program. Here I have a problem I executed the program in Eclipse today.

```
public void cvOnClick (View cvView) {
    EditText KilogramsInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Kilograms);
    EditText HeightInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Height);
    TextView BmiOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Bmi);
    DecimalFormat BmiFormat = new DecimalFormat(".#####");
    Double Heightdouble = Math.pow(Integer.parseInt(HeightInput.getText().toString()), 2);          

    String outcome = BmiFormat.format(Integer.parseInt(KilogramsInput.getText().toString())/Heightdouble);
    BmiOutput.setText(outcome);
}
```

As the original purpose of this program that should be square the number of height. The execution in Eclipse there is no error. But when I put the data(decimal) in the AVD, it shows: `the application has stopped unexpectedly`.

Pls let me know what can I do at this moment?

Thanks for your all help! brad

Answer (score 6):

You're using `Integer.parseInt()`, but it gets confused when you put in a `double` instead of an `int`. Use `Double.parseDouble()` instead of `Integer.parseInt()` and it should work.

Answer (score 3):

If you enter a non integer value in the kilograms or height edit text you are going to get an exception because your are trying to parse them as integers. Use `Double.parseDouble()` instead of `Integer.parseInt()`